# MySQL query sent to beanstalk queue on opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, beanstalkd

I am currently developing a website based on open cart and found myself in the position where I need some MySQL queries to run in background due to heavy load.

Basically I need to update my product table with new prices. Since my product table has over 2 million entries, queries started to work slowly.

I have installed pheanstalk client, and I have the latest opencart version.
Here is my code:

```
require_once('pheanstalk_init.php');

$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');

$pheanstalk
 ->useTube('mytube')
 ->put($this->model_catalog_trade_markup->editTradeMarkup($this->request- >get['trade_markup_id'],$this->request->post));

$job = $pheanstalk
->watch('mytube')
->ignore('default')
->reserve();

$pheanstalk->delete($job);

$this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/trade_markup', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
```

My problem is that the query runs as normal (>30sec) and is not being sent to queue or it waits for the results to send them through. That is my concern, and I'm pretty sure I'm lost:) as I dont understand how is it working.

Any info on how can I check the results or what am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the model:

```
public function editTradeMarkup($markup_id, $data){
    // TradeMarkup General Data
    $sql = "
    UPDATE `".DB_PREFIX."trade_mark` 
        SET name = '". $this->db->escape($data['name']) ."', type='". $data['type'] . "', amount='". $data['amount'] . "',
        conditions='"  .    serialize(array(
            "manufacturers"         => isset($data['manufacturers']) ? $data['manufacturers'] : '',
            "from_price"            => isset($data['from_price']) ? $data['from_price'] : '',
            "to_price"                  => isset($data['to_price']) ? $data['to_price'] : '',
            "universal"             => isset($data['universal']) ? $data['universal'] : ''
        )) . "' WHERE trade_mark_id = " . (int)$markup_id
    ;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $products = $this->getProducts($data);
    $in = array();

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_trade_mark` WHERE trade_mark_id = " . (int)$markup_id);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $in[] = $product['product_id'];

        if($data['type'] == 'procent'){
            $price = $product['list_price'] + ($product['list_price'] * $data['amount'] / 100);
        }else{
            $price = $product['list_price'] + $data['amount'];
        }



        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `".DB_PREFIX."product_trade_mark` 
            SET trade_mark_id = '" . $markup_id . "',product_id = '" . $product['product_id'] . "', price='" . $price . "', priority = '1'");
    }

    if(empty($in)) return;
    $in = '(' . implode(',', $in) . ')';
    $this->db->query("UPDATE `".DB_PREFIX."product` p SET price = (SELECT price FROM product_trade_mark ptm WHERE p.product_id = ptm.product_id ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE product_id IN " . $in . "");

}
```

Comment: What about showing us the query that you have in `catalog/model/catalog/trade_markup.php::editTradeMarkup()`? Maybe we can refactor and speed up the query a little...

Comment: I have edited my question. Thx!! Anyway, the query is not the problem. Updating over 100k products cant be much faster. My issue is why the query is not being sent to queue and run it in background. Now, I still have to wait for it to finish.